# The meaning between raw and calibrated S parameters

Tags: rf, calibration, s-parameters, vna

- VNA: E5071C
- Cal kit: 85033E
- DUT: cable end bandpass filter

This figure shows measuring S21 of filter:

[image: Real and imaginary parts of S21]

Upper figure shows real part of S21 and lower one shows imaginary part of S21.

Blue line is raw S21 data. Orange line is calibrated S21 data.

According to the measuring results. Raw S21 has oscillation curve but calibrated S21 data seems like the envelope of an oscillating raw S21. So are there any meaning of physics between raw and calibrated S21 data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw measurement is exactly what was measured by the instrument. It includes any non-idealities of the instrument and it includes the effects of whatever cable connects the instrument to the DUT.

The calibrated (or corrected) measurement has mathematically de-embedded the instrument non-idealities and the effects of the cable between the instrument and the DUT to tell you (very nearly) how the DUT itself would respond if you could connect an ideal VNA to it with no intervening cable.

The reason for the oscillation is most likely due to the phase delay of the cable between the instrument ports and the DUT. If you plot the response in terms of magnitude and phase instead of real and imaginary parts, you should see the phase increasing rapidly with frequency in the raw measurement, and increasing much less rapidly in the corrected measurement, due to the de-embedding of the cable (and other) delays in the measurement system.

Answer (score 0):

For the most crude interpretation, you have taken out the main portion of the electrical length of the reflection around 6 GHz from the raw data. In the calibrated data, the reflection vector now only spins slowly with frequency, rather than very quickly in the raw data. There are also amplitude changes, which are the effect of fixing the port match and the directivity, but they are fairly small.